# Android SQLite select by non-primary key column

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have created my sqlite database using SQLiteAssetHelper and I can perform CRUD operations just fine. However, I can not get the following Select statement to return any rows:

```
String query = "Select * from Student where serial=?";

Cursor c = rawQuery(query, String[]{serial.trim()});
```

The serial value is initially null, and is updated with in the application. My update query is here:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("serial", serial.trim());
cv.put("isactivated", 1);

//This returns "1" meaning 1 row was affected
mDb.update("Student", cv, "uid=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(student.getUid())});
```

The serial field in my database is not the primary key. Is this why it is not working? A select statement by the primary key works fine:

```
String query = "Select * from Student where id=?";

Cursor c = rawQuery(query, String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

Comment: Is it returning 0 row? what ur logcat says?

Comment: You can also get data from database using non-primary key and can you please check serial value after update ?

Comment: mate, does the `serial` column has an actual value or it's null? Is the update actually doing anything? The select query looks just fine...make sure that `serial` has a value other than `null` otherwise the select query will not return anything

Comment: db.update() returns the number of rows affected. And it is returning one. That means it is working correct?

Comment: I get the serial from an outside source. And no it is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I figured it out. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone. I was wrapping my database transactions with

```
db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();

//Database operations

db.endTransaction();
```

I was reading the documentation for beginTransactionNonExclusive(), and all changes made will be rolled back at the end of the transaction unless you call

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful()
```

before calling

```
db.endTransaction();
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in this way

`db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)`

```
Cursor c = db.query("Student",null,"serial"+"=?",new String[]{serial.trim()},null, null, null);
```

Do necessary change like your table name if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try it right now

Answer (score 0):

looks like your serial column in TEXT.

Use like clause instead of =

example

```
db.query("Student",null,"serial like '%?%' ",new String[]{serial.trim()},null, null, null);
```

% is not required if it is perfect match

```
db.query("Student",null,"serial like '?' ",new String[]{serial.trim()},null, null, null);
```